# An abelian group of a certain order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find all the abelian groups of order less than or equal to $40$ up to isomorphism. Here is what I came up with:

$\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

$\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{20}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}$.

$\mathbb{Z}_{8} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$.

Answer (score 7):

You found all abelian groups, up to isomorphism, of order *equal to* $40$. There are MANY more abelian groups with orders *less than* $40$.

It wouldn't be difficult to find ***all*** the abelian groups, up to isomorphism, of order less than or equal to $40$; it would just take a bit of time.

You can start simply with knowing the trivial group is abelian and cyclic. And of course, there are all the abelian and cyclic groups of prime order less than $40$ for which there is one and only one group per prime $p:\; \mathbb Z_p,\;$ for $p$ equal to each of $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37$.

Then it's simply breaking all the *composite numbers* less than 40 (since we've covered $40$) into their corresponding *prime factors*, and applying the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups, just as you did for abelian groups of order $40$.

Comment: short and sweet! +1

Comment: Ahh man. That will be quite a list. So, for example theirs $7$ different abelian groups for order $32$? And I need to do this all the way to $40$?

Answer (score 3):

The $68$ non-isomorphic abelian groups of order at most $40$ can be found quickly using [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) using the code:

```
S:=Concatenation(List([1..40],n->AllSmallGroups(n,IsAbelian)));
for G in S do
  Print(StructureDescription(G),"\n");
od;
```

which outputs:

```
1
C2
C3
C4
C2 x C2
C5
C6
C7
C8
C4 x C2
C2 x C2 x C2
C9
C3 x C3
C10
C11
C12
C6 x C2
C13
C14
C15
C16
C4 x C4
C8 x C2
C4 x C2 x C2
C2 x C2 x C2 x C2
C17
C18
C6 x C3
C19
C20
C10 x C2
C21
C22
C23
C24
C12 x C2
C6 x C2 x C2
C25
C5 x C5
C26
C27
C9 x C3
C3 x C3 x C3
C28
C14 x C2
C29
C30
C31
C32
C8 x C4
C16 x C2
C4 x C4 x C2
C8 x C2 x C2
C4 x C2 x C2 x C2
C2 x C2 x C2 x C2 x C2
C33
C34
C35
C36
C18 x C2
C12 x C3
C6 x C6
C37
C38
C39
C40
C20 x C2
C10 x C2 x C2
```

Comment: I love how these CAS programs are so elegant and direct with code snippets like this! +1